# Comparing two Objects which implement the same interface for equality / equivalence - Design help

Tags: java

I have an interface and two objects implementing that interface, massively simplied;

```
public interface MyInterface {
    public int getId();
    public int getName();
    ...
}

public class A implements MyInterface {
    ...
}

public class B implements MyInterface {
    ...
}
```

We are migrating from using one implementation to the other but I need to check that the objects of type B that are generated are equivalent to those of type A. Specifically I mean that for all of the interface methods an object of Type A and Type B will return the same value (I'm just checking my code for generating this objects is correct).

How would you go about this?

```
Map<String, MyInterface> oldGeneratedObjects = getOldGeneratedObjects();
Map<String, MyInterface> newGeneratedObjects = getNewGeneratedObjects();

// TODO: Establish that for each Key the Values in the two maps return equivalent values.
```

I'm looking for good coding practices and style here. I appreciate that I could just iterate through one key set pulling out both objects which should be equivalent and then just call all the methods and compare, I'm just thinking there may be a cleaner, more extensible way and I'm interested to learn what options there might be.

Would it be appropriate / possible / advised to override equals or implement Comparable?

Thanks in advance,

Gavin

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would implement a custom version of `equals` in the test class, not inside any of those implementation classes (since it would clash with the regular `equals` contract). Something like:

```
boolean equals(A a, B b) ...
```

I understand that this check would be required only during the migration period, so the normal `equals` methods of each implementation should not be affected by this. Namely, `A.equals` should only return `true` for an equal instance of `A`, and should always return `false` for an instance of `B`. And vice versa.

Once the migration is over, you no longer need class A neither the tester class, and you can continue using class B without needing to touch its implementation.

Note that if `MyInterface` (or `A` and `B`) extends `Comparable`, you should also test that the implementations in `A` and `B` are equivalent.

(And you surely know that if you implement `equals` you must also implement `hashCode`.)

Comment: Fantastic, this makes sense to me, I'll write the code as a test and keep the implementations out of the equation.

You're right that this code will only be used during the migration.